# How to count the number of buckets needed to split a number into buckets of max size X, where each split has to be Y splits

Tags: python, java, algorithm, recursion, bucket

I encoutered this problem on a leetcode github and can't wrap my head around it. I figured you could use some kind of recursion, where the end criterion is "bucket is smaller than or equal to max bucket value, return one", but I am having a hard time getting there.

I've tried this (in Python):

```
def buckets(height, max, splits):
    
    if(splits >= height):
        return math.ceil(height / max) + 1
    else:
        return math.ceil(height / max)
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Python, but I'd be open to any solution in a language a Java/Python person can understand

Comment: Then you should add the tags so that people who have subscribed to those languages get your question highlighted to them. Otherwise you severely restrict your audience. It's also worthwhile explicitly stating the languages that you'd like as part of the answer.

Comment: It seems to be added now!

Comment: I added the tags.

Comment: I disagree on the language tags; the algorithm tag alone gives enough visibility to the right people, and getting genpop to look too often just results in a closed question.

Answer (score 0):

For recursion, you need a base case and a recursive case.

> You could use some kind of recursion, where the end criterion is
> “[height] is smaller than or equal to max bucket value, return one”.

This is half of a correct base case. The other half is doing one round
of splits when `max_size < height <= splits * max_size`.

For the recursive case, we need to determine the optimal way to split.
This turns out to be splitting off `splits - 1` buckets of size
`max_size` (the bigger the better) and handling the remainder. See the
Python below. (I would use iteration instead because of Python’s stack
limit.)

To prove correctness, we need to do some math. The base cases are
correct by inspection. For the recursive case, since `n` buckets hold at
most `n * max_size`, we need at least `height / max_size` buckets. We
also know that the number of buckets must be one plus a multiple of
`splits - 1`, since we start with one and add `splits - 1` with each
round of splits. Hence, the number of buckets in the optimal solution is
at least `height / max_size` rounded up to the nearest one plus a
multiple of `splits - 1`. The recursive case matches this bound exactly,
so it’s optimal.

```py
def buckets(height, max_size, splits):
    if height <= max_size:
        return 1
    if height <= splits * max_size:
        return splits
    return (splits - 1) + buckets(height - (splits - 1) * max_size, max_size, splits)
```